# How to kill spark/yarn job via livy

Tags: rest, azure, azure-hdinsight, livy

I am trying to submit spark job via livy using rest api. But if I run same script multiple time it runs multiple instance of a job with different job ID's. I am looking a way to kill spark/yarn job running with same name before starting a new one. Livy document says (https://github.com/cloudera/livy#batch) delete the batch job, but livy sessions doesn't return application name, just application id is returned.

Is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

For Livy version 0.7.0, the following works.

Where the Session ID you want to stop is `1`:

- python

```py
import requests
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
session_url = 'http://your-livy-server-ip:8998/sessions/1'
requests.delete(session_url, headers=headers)
```

- shell

```sh
curl -X DELETE http://your-livy-server-ip:8998/sessions/1
```

See https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use LivyClient API to submit spark jobs using Livy Server.
LivyClient API has a stop method which can used to kill the job.

LivyClient.close(true);

Comment: Do you know where to find info and examples for LivyClient API? I can't find anything in the official Livy page

Answer (score 0):

Sessions that were active when the Livy server was stopped may need to be killed manually. Use the tools from your cluster manager to achieve that (for example, the yarn command line tool).

Run the following command to find the application IDs of the interactive jobs started through Livy.

**yarn application -list**

Run the following command to kill those jobs.

**yarn application –kill "Application ID"**

Refer: “https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-known-issues#livy-leaks-interactive-session”.